# InstallShield: the following app should be closed dialog shows empty list

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, uninstallation

When running uninstall while my app is running "The following applications should be closed before continuing the installation" dialog appears, but the list of applications is empty. Does anybody know the reasons and maybe a solution? Setup is developed with InstallShield2012

That's how it looks:

[image: That's how it looks]

Comment: Were you able to find this dialog? Solve the problem @Bor1ss..?

Comment: @poli_g Yes, finally found out that this dialog shows values from field "File Description" of exe file. In case it is empty, blank line is shown. For .net projects You need to specify "AssemblyTitle" in AssemblyInfo.cs